# Multiple Adressof's to 1 sub

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a dynamic input form. But to do this I need to be able to pass multiple adressof's to 1 sub. Is this possible?
Here is my code:

```
    Public Function AddNewcombobox() 'As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Dim cmbSoort As New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()

    Me.Controls.Add(cmbSoort)
    cmbSoort.Top = cLeft
    cmbSoort.Left = 62
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Maak een keuze")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Behuizingen")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Moederborden")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Processoren")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Grafische kaarten")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Geheugen")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("DVD/Blu-ray")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Harddisks")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("SSD")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Voedingen")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Invoerapparaten")
    cmbSoort.Items.Add("Monitoren")
    cmbSoort.SelectedIndex = 0
    cmbSoort.Name = "Soort" & mintI
    AddHandler cmbSoort.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf IndexVeranderd
    Return cmbSoort
End Function

Public Sub AddNewName()
    Dim cmbName As New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()

    Me.Controls.Add(cmbName)
    cmbName.Top = cLeft
    cmbName.Left = 292
    cmbName.Items.Add("Maak een keuze")
    cmbName.Name = "Naam" & mintI
    cmbName.Enabled = False
    CmbPrijs.Enabled = False
    txtStuks.Enabled = False
    'AddHandler AddNewcombobox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf IndexVeranderd
    cLeft = cLeft + 40
    mintI += 1
End Sub

Private Sub cmbNaam_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'CmbPrijs.SelectedIndex = CmbNaam.SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub IndexVeranderd(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim ComboVeranderd = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim combonaam = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    MsgBox(combonaam.ToString)
    If ComboVeranderd.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        'ComboNaam.Enabled = False
        txtStuks.Enabled = False
    End If
    For i = 0 To EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows.Count - 1
        If ComboVeranderd.SelectedItem = EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows(i)("Soort") Then
            'ComboNaam.Enabled = True
            txtStuks.Enabled = True
            'ComboNaam.Items.Add(EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows(i)("Product naam"))
            CmbPrijs.Items.Add(EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows(i)("Prijs"))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When cmbSoort's index changes, it should send both cmbSoort and cmbName to the sub IndexVeranderd.
The trick is, cmbSoort and cmbName are generated by the functions when the user presses a button.
Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Do you have problem with your code above?

Answer (score 0):

To make a Sub handle multi combobox ..

In your case :

```
Public Sub AddNewcombobox()
  Dim cmbSoort as New ComboBox
  Dim cmbName as New ComboBox

  '.......... fill cmbSoort properties

  '.......... fill cmbName properties

  Controls.Add(cmbSoort)
  AddHandler cmbSoort.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf IndexVeranderd
  Controls.Add(cmbname)
  AddHandler cmbName.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf IndexVeranderd
End Sub
```

And the Sub handler

```
Private Sub IndexVeranderd(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

  Select Case oCB
    Case cmbSoort
      ' ................. code here

    Case cmbName
      ' ................. code here 

  End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is I can't use a switch since I need both cmbSoort and cmbName. 
Like 

`If ComboVeranderd.SelectedItem = EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows(i)("Soort") Then ComboName.Items.Add(EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows(i)("Product naam")) CmbPrijs.Items.Add(EasybyteDataSet.Stock.Rows(i)("Prijs")) End If`

It takes the selected index of cmbSoort and if that changes, it changes cmbName too. The problem is both cmbSoort and cmbName don't exist (they get generated by the functions I wrote in my first post).

Answer (score 0):

The names seem to have an number added to them if they are the same so that Soort1 is tied to Naam1 then just separate out the number and access the control directly.  This way you only need the handler for cmbSoort.

```
Dim ComboVeranderd = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
Dim combonaam = Me.Controls("Naam"+ComboVeranderd.Name.Substring(ComboVeranderd.Name.Length-1))
```

I assumed the number is only 1 digit, if not you might have to adjust for more.

If the names don't include a number this would be an efficient way to pair them up